# Redirect based on screen resolution with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

Is it possible, using JQuery, to redirect to a different index.html based upon the users screen resolution? So for example, screens upto the size 1024px wide go to 1024.html, and all others go to the normal index.html?

Id preferably like to use jQuery for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need jQuery.

You can use [screen.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.width), [which works in all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#screenview):

```
if (screen.width <= 1024) window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/1024.html")
else window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/index.html")
```

See http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/info3.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
 if ($(window).width() <= 1024) location.href = "1024.html";
```

[docs on `width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (screen.width >= 1024) {
        window.location.replace("http://example.com/1024.html");
    }
    else  {
        window.location.replace("http://example.com/index.html");
    }
});
```

Reference notes in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery) on difference between `window.location.replace` and `window.location.href`.

Comment: Good point about location.replace, but why wait until document.ready?

Comment: No particular reason for document.ready, just a natural response to a jQuery question.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `else` statement like in the answers above results in an infinite loop if it is used for the index.html (i.e. the page a user will land on by default)

**For a simple Desktop Page to Mobile Page redirect**

In the `<head>` of your index.html:

```
<script>
    if (screen.width <= 1024) {
    window.location.replace("http://www.yourMobilePage.html");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben, it seems to work but 2 issues : 
How to keep the actual page where the user is ?

- From : "http://www.example.com/PageXXX"
- To: "http://www.example.com/m" + "PageXXX"

How to auto load the script ? When resizing, the page must be refresh to be redirected.